# how can I save results of multiple select queries to a single Grid or a single file

Tags: sql-server

I have a thousand select statements like these below. I want to be able to sort them.

```
select TOP 1 [utcDT] from [Matrix].[Signal].[Specified_ACC1v2_0.0600_CWin_1440] WHERE [Joint] != 0 ORDER BY [utcDT] DESC;
select TOP 1 [utcDT] from [Matrix].[Signal].[Specified_ACC1v2_0.1100_CWin_1440] WHERE [Joint] != 0 ORDER BY [utcDT] DESC;
select TOP 1 [utcDT] from [Matrix].[Signal].[Specified_ACC1v2_0.0050_CWin_12960] WHERE [Joint] != 0 ORDER BY [utcDT] DESC;
select TOP 1 [utcDT] from [Matrix].[Signal].[Specified_ACC1v2_0.0500_CWin_18720] WHERE [Joint] != 0 ORDER BY [utcDT] DESC;
select TOP 1 [utcDT] from [Matrix].[Signal].[Specified_ACC1v2_0.1100_CWin_27360] WHERE [Joint] != 0 ORDER BY [utcDT] DESC;
select TOP 1 [utcDT] from [Matrix].[Signal].[Specified_ACC1v2_0.0700_CWin_10080] WHERE [Joint] != 0 ORDER BY [utcDT] DESC;
```

If I do "results to text" I get this:

```
utcDT
----------------------- 2019-11-26 00:00:00.000

(1 row(s) affected)

utcDT
----------------------- 2019-10-29 00:00:00.000

(1 row(s) affected)

utcDT
----------------------- 2019-12-04 00:00:00.000

(1 row(s) affected)

utcDT
----------------------- 2019-04-30 00:00:00.000

(1 row(s) affected)

utcDT
----------------------- 2019-01-02 00:00:00.000

(1 row(s) affected)

utcDT
----------------------- 2019-08-21 00:00:00.000

(1 row(s) affected)
```

What I want is this, clean results in a file, or array, so I can sort in Excel etc:

```
2019-11-26 00:00:00.000
2019-10-29 00:00:00.000
2019-12-04 00:00:00.000
2019-04-30 00:00:00.000
2019-01-02 00:00:00.000
2019-08-21 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: YOu need to use a `UNION ALL`, but this looks more like a problem with your design. Why do you have 1000 different objects for what look to be the same data?

Comment: I generate the select statements from database metadata. How can I incorporate UNION ALL in that? It a legacy thing I have 100K+ tables all exactly same...

Comment: One way is to use something like NotePad++ and create a marco..very powerfull for things like this.

Comment: @ManInMoon: You'd write `SELECT ... FROM 1st_table ... UNION ALL SELECT ... FROM 2nd_table ... ... UNION ALL SELECT ... FROM 100th_plus_table ...;`. Well, I hope you like typing. Or can use some programming language to build that query for you.

Comment: select TOP 1 [utcDT] from [Matrix].[Signal].[Specified_ACC1v2_0.0500_CWin_18720] WHERE [Joint] != 0 ORDER BY [utcDT] DESC UNION ALL

select TOP 1 [utcDT] from [Matrix].[Signal].[Specified_ACC1v2_0.1100_CWin_27360] WHERE [Joint] != 0 ORDER BY [utcDT] DESC UNION ALL

select TOP 1 [utcDT] from [Matrix].[Signal].[Specified_ACC1v2_0.0700_CWin_10080] WHERE [Joint] != 0 ORDER BY [utcDT] DESC;

Give me an error!

Sorry don't know how to format in comment

Comment: That gives a different ANSWER. I am using TOP 1...

Comment: WHy does select NOcolumn headers not work in Tools/Options/Result to text?

Comment: Oh..snap...I know you can t use ORDERBY on every SELECT with a UNION.

Answer (score 1):

This makes an assumption on the formatting of the names of your objects, but...

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SET @SQL = STUFF((SELECT N'UNION ALL' + @CRLF +
                         N'SELECT MAX(utcDT) AS utcDT' + @CRLF +
                         N'FROM Matrix.Signal.' + QUOTENAME(t.[name]) + @CRLF +
                         N'WHERE [Joint] != 0'
                  FROM Matrix.sys.schemas s
                       JOIN Matrix.sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
                  WHERE s.[name] = N'Signal'
                    AND t.[name] LIKE N'Specified[_]ACC1v2[_]0.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][_]CWIN[_]%'
                  FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,11,N'') + N';'

--SELECT @SQL; --Your debugging friend

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Of course, like I said, it looks like what you really need to do it fix your design. Having 1000+ objects with the same definition means you have a major design problem.

Comment: "...we're not worthy...we're not worthy..." really...amazing!

Answer (score 0):

Select a.utcDT 
from
(select TOP 1 [utcDT], 1 rn from [Matrix].[Signal].[Specified_ACC1v2_0.0600_CWin_1440] WHERE [Joint] != 0

union all

select TOP 1 [utcDT], 2 rn from [Matrix].[Signal].[Specified_ACC1v2_0.1100_CWin_1440] WHERE [Joint] != 0

UNION all

select TOP 1 [utcDT], 3 rn from [Matrix].[Signal].[Specified_ACC1v2_0.0050_CWin_12960] WHERE [Joint] != 0

union all

select TOP 1 [utcDT], 4 rn from [Matrix].[Signal].[Specified_ACC1v2_0.0500_CWin_18720] WHERE [Joint] != 0

union all

select TOP 1 [utcDT], 5 rn from [Matrix].[Signal].[Specified_ACC1v2_0.1100_CWin_27360] WHERE [Joint] != 0

union all

select TOP 1 [utcDT], 6 rn from [Matrix].[Signal].[Specified_ACC1v2_0.0700_CWin_10080] WHERE [Joint] != 0 order by rn)
a order by a.rn asc

Right click on result output and save as text file